# Is there way to create Gantt Chart in IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1 R2?

Tags: cognos-11

I am trying to build a Gantt chart in IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1 R2. There is no option in Visualizations where I can create Gantt chart. Is there any other way I can create a Gantt chart. Data I have is One project with multiple activities and planned start Date planned finish date actual start date and actual finish date.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own visualizations or downloading a gantt?

Comment: In Visualization, there is no option for creating a Gantt chart. How can I download the Gannt Chart? I eventually want to create in Cognos and then schedule that report for a business user.

Answer (score 1):

For Cognos, there is Gantt visualization available in RAVE which can be downloaded from https://community.ibm.com/community/user/businessanalytics/blogs/kevin-mcfaul/2016/06/24/cognos-business-intelligence-cognos-analytics-all-visualizations

alternatively, you can create Gantt using Crosstab which will be a bit tricky, to begin with, but can be customized as required.